# CKEditor getting displayed twice

Tags: reactjs, ckeditor, antd

I am trying to integrate CKEditor with antd in a React application. This is my code:

```
 <Form {...layout} form={form} name="control-hooks" onFinish={onFinish}>
      <Form.Item
        name="content"
        label="Category"
        rules={[
          {
            required: true,
          },
        ]}
      >
      <CKEditor editor={classicEditor} onChange={onCategoryChange} />
      </Form.Item>
      <Form.Item {...tailLayout}>
        <Button type="primary" htmlType="submit">
          Submit
        </Button>
        <Button htmlType="button" onClick={onReset}>
          Reset
        </Button>
      </Form.Item>
    </Form>
```

However, the component is displayed twice after rendering
[image: here]

Is this a bug from antd?

Answer (score 1):

The reason is the React.StrictMode wrapper, in your ReactDOM.render,
try to comment or delete strict mode tag,then you will get a single render.

Answer (score 0):

Believe it's related to `strict mode`, When you enable Strict Mode, React will intentionally invoke component methods (such as render()) twice in order to help catch unexpected side effects in the code.
Here is an example

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import CKEditor from "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-react";
import ClassicEditor from "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic";

function MyComponent() {
  const [content, setContent] = useState("");

  const handleChange = (event, editor) => {
    const data = editor.getData();
    setContent(data);
  };

  // Wrap the CKEditor component in React.memo()
  const Editor = React.memo(() => (
    <CKEditor
      editor={ClassicEditor}
      data={content}
      onChange={handleChange}
    />
  ));

  return <Editor />;
}

export default MyComponent;
```

Comment: this is not a proper way to split up a react component and would be an anti-pattern. It would be better to just extra the `Editor` into it's own component outside of the `MyComponent`.